# Ruby regular expressions for finding words

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm quite new to regular expressions. I am using the regular expression:

```
/\w+/
```

To check for words, and it's obvious that this will have problems with punctuation, but I'm not quite sure how to change this regular expression. For example, when I run this command from a class I made:

```
Wordify.new.regex(/\w+/).string("This sentence isn't 'the best-example, isn't it not?...").display
```

I get the output:

```
-----------
this: 1
sentence: 1
isn: 2
t: 2
the: 1
best: 1
example: 1
it: 1
not: 1
-----------
```

How can I adjust the regular expression so that it matches words with apostrophes, like: **isn't** as one word, but will only match **the** when searching **'the** or **the'**. Hyphens in the middle of a word like **stack-overflow** should match return **stack** and **overflow** separately, which this already does.

Additionally, words shouldn't be able to start or end with numbers, like **test1241** or **436test** should become **test**, but **te7st** is okay. Plain numbers should not be recognised.

Sorry, I know this is a big ask, but I'm not sure where to start with regex. Would be grateful if you could also explain what the expression means if possible.

Comment: Remember that in Ruby and a lot of regular expression libraries `\w` includes underscore `_` as a valid character.

Comment: Note that by excluding `"the'"` you are also excluding the possessive form of words that end with an `"s"`, as in `"I like Chris' hat"`.

Comment: Other than the first or last character of a string, you said each "interior" character can be a letter, number or apostrophe. Can the interior letters be anything else?

Comment: No, the interior character should not be able to be anything else, including other punctuation like underscores.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "This is 2a' 4test' of my agréable re4'gex, n'est-ce pas?"

r = /
    [[:alpha:]]            # match a letter
    (?:                    # begin the outer non-capture group
      (?:[[:alpha:]]|\d|') # match a letter, digit or apostrophe in a non-capture group
      *                    # execute the above non-capture group zero or more times
      [[:alpha:]]          # match a letter
    )?                     # close the outer non-capture group and make it optional
    /x                     # free-spacing regex definition mode

str.scan r
  #=> ["This", "is", "a", "test", "of", "my", "agréable", "re4'gex", "n'est", "ce", "pas"]
```

Note the outer capture group is needed in case the string to be matched is a single character.

Hmmm. Maybe we should add a hyphen to the inner non-capture group.

```
r = /[[:alpha:]](?:(?:[[:alpha:]]|\d|'|-)*[[:alpha:]])?/
str.scan r
  #=> ["This", "is", "a", "test", "of", "my", "agréable", "re4'gex", "n'est-ce", "pas"]
```

I now rarely use the word-matching character `\w`, mainly because it matches the underscore, as well as letters and digits. Instead I reach for a [POSIX bracket expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html) (search "POSIX"), which has the added (perhaps primary) benefit that it is not English-centric. For example, matching a word character with the exception of an underscore is `[[:alnum:]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something basic using:

```
/[a-z]+(?:'[a-z]+)*/i
```

To extend it to allow words like `a2b` and avoid `123abc` `abc123` and or plain numbers:

```
/[a-z]+(?:'[a-z]+|\d+[a-z]+)*/i
```

There's no special regex features used in the two patterns, only basics.

Comment: `"is3't"[/[a-z]+(?:'[a-z]+|\d+[a-z]+)*/i] #=> "is"`. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Try scanning the string using the `[[:alpha:]]` POSIX character class:

```ruby
s = "This a sentence isn't 'the best-example, isn't it not?... a1 2b 3c3 d4d 555 stack-overflow"
s.scan(/[[:alpha:]](?:['\w]*[[:alpha:]])?/)
# => ["This", "a", "sentence", "isn't", "the", "best", "example", "isn't", "it", "not", "a", "b", "c", "d4d", "stack", "overflow"]
```

**[First attempt]**

I split the string into tokens separated by whitespace or hyphens then clean up each token per your rules, since it seems like they might be adjusted as you refine your problem:

```ruby
def tokenize(str)
  tokens = str.split(/(?:\s+|-)/)
  tokens.reduce([]) do |memo, token|
    token.gsub!(/(^\W+|\W+$)/, '')    # Strip enclosing non-words
    token.gsub!(/(^\d+|\d+$)/, '')    # Strip enclosing digits
    memo + (token=='' ? [] : [token]) # Ignore the empty string
  end
end

s = "This sentence isn't 'the best-example, isn't it not?... a1 2b 3c3 d4d 555 stack-overflow"
puts tokenize(s).inspect
#   ["This", "sentence", "isn't", "the", "best", "example", "isn't", "it", "not", "a", "b", "c", "d4d", "stack", "overflow"]
```

Clearly this solution doesn't use just regular expressions but for my money it's much easier to understand and modify then (what I imagine) a big regex would look like!