# Check value in array in string

Tags: ruby

I am creating a takeaway restaurant database, which can be accessed by the `Managers` of each store. One of the database tables in called `Product`, and it has a column called `product_name`. The `product_name` is a string with multiple words. I'm trying to check whether the `product_name` contains meat, and then tell the user whether it is or is not suitable for vegetarians.

This is the code I have. I was trying to create a `meats` array, and check `product_name` against it. I don't think the `if not` statement is correct.

```
class Checkveg
  def self.runcheck(product_name)
    meats = ["lamb", "beef", "pork", "prawn", "chicken", "fish"]
    meats.each { |item|
      if product_name.include? item
        puts "Not suitable for vegans or vegetarians"
      end
    }
    puts "Suitable for vegans or vegetarians" if not meats.include? product_name
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:

I was able to fix it

```
noVeg = false
meats = ["lamb", "beef", "pork", "prawn", "chicken", "fish"]
meats.any? { |item|
  if product_name.include? item
    noVeg = true
    break
  end
}
if noVeg == true
  puts "Not suitable for vegetarians"
else
  puts "Suitable for vegetarians"
end
```

Comment: I haven't implemented it get, and i would like input to whether the coding is correct.

Comment: `meats.include? x` is going to be true if `x` is in the array `meats`. Do you expect `product_name` ever to be an element of the array? Also, look up the [Ruby Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html) class. There are other interesting methods such as `.any?` or `.all?` that may be of interest for your problem and make it simpler.

Comment: @lurker `puts "Suitable for vegans or vegetarians" if not meats.include? product_name`. Would that also work, even if the product_name is a string with multiple words?

Comment: `meats.include? product_name` will be true only if `product_name` is an element of the array `meats`. I suspect that it never is. Also, see my prior comment about `.any?` and `.all?`.

Comment: It took me 1 minute and 27 seconds to load your code into console and run it. Why don't you do the same and see what works and what doesn't?

Comment: @lurker so, let's say product_name = "Beef curry", would the loop catch it then and then the "if not" would be ignored?

Comment: @jvillian, because I'm new to Ruby and ruby on Rails and I don't want to break it.

Comment: `meats.include? "Beef curry"` is never true in your current code since "Beef curry" is not an element of the `meats` array.

Comment: @lurker, OK, is there a "contains" method, or how would I fix it?

Comment: What would you want "contains" to do? And if you want to know if it exists, check the documentation for the class you are operating on. It's unclear how you're wanting that statement to behave. As an idea: study what `meats.any? { |m| product_name.include? m }` means. Please look at the link I provided for Ruby Array methods in my prior comment. It's helpful to read through the documentation to find a suitable method to meet your needs.

Comment: @lurker, I got it. I updated my original question to reflect this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Questions should not contain answers. If you wish to post your own solution make it an answer. It's not at all uncommon to see that done. Often the asker has worked out an answer before posting.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the `any?` method properly. You should use it's return value like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

meats = ["lamb", "beef", "pork", "prawn", "chicken", "fish"]

product_name = "Beef curry"

noVeg = meats.any? do |item|
    product_name.downcase.include? item
end

if noVeg == true
    puts "Not suitable for vegetarians"
else
    puts "Suitable for vegetarians"
end
```

I also added `downcase` since in the comment above you wrote beef with a capital `b`.

Comment: `if noVeg == true` is also an anti-pattern. You could simply do `if noVeg`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r true, that's what you get when copying OP's code, the point was to show the `any` method though.

Comment: I thought as much. Maybe the comment was better suited under the question itself, but nonetheless it's worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest, first to extract the words from the product name. I used the regex from a [good example by Cary Swoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41838454/5239030) for this method. But you can use whatever regex fits best for you:

```
product_name = "Chicken_Wings 1"
product_words = product_name.scan(/[[:alpha:]](?:(?:[[:alpha:]]|\d|')*[[:alpha:]])?/x).map(&:downcase)

#=> ["chicken", "wings"]
```

Then check if none of the `product_words` is included in `meats` array:

```
no_veg = product_words.none? { |w| meats.include? w }
#=> false
```

In this case `product_name = "Carrots and onions"`, `no_veg = true`.

Comment: When using this approach you could also use `(product_words & meats).empty?` instead of `product_words.none? { |w| meats.include? w }`. Although the result would be the reverse, eg. `veg`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a regex using the `meats` array.

```
meats_regex_string = meats.map(&Regexp.method(:escape)).join('|')
meats_regex = Regexp.new(meats_regex_string)
# or /#{meats_regex_string}/
product_name.match?(meats_regex)
```

You can leave out `.map(&Regexp.method(:escape))` if you know your strings don't contain any regex special characters like `(`, `*`, `?`, `|`, etc.

If you don't care about the character casing use:

```
meats_regex = Regexp.new(meats_regex_string, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
# or /#{meats_regex_string}/i
```

Comment: Since you're new to Ruby it might be worth pointing out that `.map(&Regexp.method(:escape))` could also be written as `.map { |meat| Regexp.escape(meat) }`.